# Why should this question be split?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closing-questions

[**The Question**](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/30739/long-dark-tea-time-of-the-soul-can-someone-explain-the-plot)

So the OP is asking for a plot synopsis to clear up his confusion on some plot points in the novel. That is EXACTLY on-topic according to the FAQ. In fact, it's the very first bullet point. The OP then goes on to enumerate his particular problems and things that he didn't understand in a list of eight questions, to make sure that he would get the answer that he is looking for. All of the questions are still under the same basic question of "Please explain the plot of this sci-fi thing", so why should he be required to split them up?

Questions 1, 2, 4, 6, & 8 seem directly related to even a cursory summary of the plot as three of them are addressed on the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Long_Dark_Tea-Time_of_the_Soul) page. 5 & 7 are both just questions about the powers of the protagonist (also appropriate for a plot summary). The only one that seems to be an outlier is 3 and I feel certain it would fit into any good answer to the question.

Answer (score 6):

The answer that got posted before it was closed is basically the entire reason:

> I can't answer all of these, but I think you have a few misconceptions.

Remember, the StackExchange network works off the premise that each question has one correct answer.  This "question" is actually a list of vaguely-related *specific* questions that makes the post far, far too broad.

The user isn't asking for a general clarification of the plot; they have lots of smaller questions *related to* the plot.  The difference is that they can mostly be answered separately from each other, and by attempting to combine them into one massive question, you're going to get answers that address only parts of it.

Questions 1 and 2 look related; they can probably be posted as one question.  All the remaining ones look independent of each other (I haven't read this work), so they'd best be posted separately, although posting so many in a row may well cause a downvoting-backlash with other users - best to space them out over a day or two.